# Single-qubit rotations on a subspace within two-qubit unitary

Tags: quantum-gate, gate-synthesis, matrix-representation, pauli-gates

I would like to implement the operation
$$
U(a,b) = \exp\left(i \frac{a}{2} (XX + YY)  + i \frac{b}{2} (XY - YX) \right)
$$

($a,b \in \mathbb{R}$) without using Baker-Campbell-Hausdorf expansion, which at first seems necessary since $[(XY - YX), (XX + YY)] \neq 0$. My intuition is that this can be done in the same way that $\exp(i(aX + bY))$ does not require a BCH expansion to implement. The above operation is generated by these two matrices:

\begin{align}
 i \frac{a}{2} (XX + YY)\rightarrow i a
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} \\
 i \frac{b}{2} (XY - YX)\rightarrow i b\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \text{-}i & 0 \\
0 & i & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}

Since sum of these matrices is proportional to the operator $(aX - bY)$ in the $(|01\rangle,|10\rangle)$ subspace it seems possible that the operation can be done with a general single-qubit rotation $\text{R}_\hat{n}$ in that subspace. Taking the (unnormalized) unit vector $\hat{n} = a\hat{x} - b\hat{y}$ this rotation is given by

$$
\text{R}_\hat{n} (\theta) = \cos\frac{\theta}{2} + i \sin \frac{\theta}{2} (a X - b Y)
$$

so that the operation can be implemented as

$$
U(a, b) = \text{CNOT}^{2\rightarrow 1} \text{CR}_{\hat{n}}(\theta)^{1\rightarrow 2} \text{CNOT}^{2\rightarrow 1}
$$

where $\text{CR}_{\hat{n}}(\theta)$ is a controlled version of $\text{R}_\hat{n}$ and $i\rightarrow j$ indicates an operation on qubit $j$ controlled by qubit $i$. My main concern is that since neither $(XY - YX)$ nor $(XX + YY)$ has support in the $|00\rangle, |11\rangle$ subspace that there's something missing or wrong in this process.

My question is, is this a valid decomposition for $U(a, b)$ or is there something wrong in the above reasoning?

Comment: You can just multiply the 4 by 4 matrices to check your answer.

Comment: I don't know the matrix representation of $U(a,b)$

Comment: You can find a matrix representation of a 2-qubit gate using a math software package, e.g. scipy enables you to compute matrix exponentials using [`scipy.linalg.expm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.expm.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is correct. In particular, sandwiching a controlled rotation between two CNOT gates is a common technique for implementing rotations on the $|01\rangle, |10\rangle$ subspace on hardware that does not implement it natively.

We can justify your approach using the fact that if $A$ has eigendecomposition

$$
A = \sum_i \lambda_i|i\rangle\langle i|
$$

then $e^A$ has eigendecomposition

$$
e^A = \sum_i e^{\lambda_i}|i\rangle\langle i|.
$$

Consequently, if $A$ is block diagonal

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
A_1 & & & \\
& A_2 & & \\
& & \ddots & \\
& & & A_k \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

then so is $e^A$

$$
e^A = \begin{pmatrix}
e^{A_1} & & & \\
& e^{A_2} & & \\
& & \ddots & \\
& & & e^{A_k} \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

In the present case

$$
\frac{a}{2}(XX + YY) + \frac{b}{2}(XY - YX) = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & & \\
& aX - bY & \\
& & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

so

$$
\exp\left(i\frac{a}{2}(XX + YY) + i\frac{b}{2}(XY - YX)\right) = \begin{pmatrix}
e^0 & & \\
& e^{iaX-ibY} & \\
& & e^0
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & & \\
& R_{\hat n}(2t) & \\
& & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

where $n$  is the normalized real 3-vector $(-a, b, 0) / t = (-\alpha, \beta, 0)$, $\hat n = \beta Y-\alpha X$ and $t = \|n\|_2 = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$.

In particular, we do not need to be concerned about the subspace $|00\rangle, |11\rangle$ because it is the eigenspace of the operator in the exponent associated with eigenvalue zero which means that $U(a, b)$ acts on it as identity.

---

Note that in practice it is sometimes possible to avoid using Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff by bringing the terms of the exponent into a form in which they commute, e.g. by regrouping the terms

$$
\begin{align}
U(a,b) &= \exp\left(i \frac{a}{2} (XX + YY)  + i \frac{b}{2} (XY - YX) \right) \\
&= \exp\left(\frac{i}{2} X\otimes(aX + bY)  + \frac{i}{2} Y\otimes(aY - bX) \right) \\
\end{align}
$$

where $X\otimes(aX+bY)$ and $Y\otimes(aY-bX)$ commute. Therefore,

$$
\begin{align}
U(a, b) &= \exp\left(\frac{i}{2} X\otimes(aX + bY)\right) \exp\left(\frac{i}{2} Y \otimes(aY - bX)\right) \\
&= \exp\left(\frac{it}{2} X\otimes(\alpha X + \beta Y)\right) \exp\left(\frac{it}{2} Y\otimes(\alpha Y - \beta X)\right)
\end{align}
$$

where $t = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}, \alpha = \frac{a}{t},\beta = \frac{b}{t}$ as before. Notice that $[X\otimes(\alpha X + \beta Y)]^2 = I$ and $[Y\otimes(\alpha Y - \beta X)]^2 = I$ so

$$
\exp\left(\frac{it}{2} X\otimes(\alpha X + \beta Y)\right) = I \cos\frac{t}{2} + i X\otimes(\alpha X + \beta Y) \sin\frac{t}{2} \\
\exp\left(\frac{it}{2} Y\otimes(\alpha Y - \beta X)\right) = I \cos\frac{t}{2} + i Y\otimes(\alpha Y - \beta X) \sin\frac{t}{2}
$$

(c.f. equation $(4.7)$  on p.175 in Nielsen & Chuang). Thus,

$$
U(a, b) = II \cos^2\frac{t}{2} + ZZ\sin^2\frac{t}{2} + i\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}(XX + YY) + \frac{\beta}{2}(XY - YX)\right)\sin t.
$$

In matrix representation

$$
U(a, b) = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos t & (-\beta + i\alpha)\sin t & 0 \\
0 & (\beta + i\alpha)\sin t &\cos t & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

where we recognize the middle $2\times 2$ block as $R_{\hat n}(2t)$ with $\hat n = \beta Y-\alpha X$ as before.