How to apply gates on a subspace of a superposition of qubits?
Let us say that I have the state $a|00\rangle + b|01\rangle + c|10\rangle + d|11\rangle$. I wish to apply a one-qubit unitary (a $2\times2$ matrix) U on the subspace spanned by $|01\rangle$ and $|10\rangle$ (equivalently $|00\rangle$ and $|01\rangle$, after shifting the basis). Essentially I want the state $|\psi\rangle = U(b|01\rangle + c|10\rangle) + a|00\rangle + d|11\rangle$.
How can I do this in Qiskit? I tried methods which involve resetting the one qubit to 0 or involving mid-circuit measurements, but they seem to destroy the superposition of states, which I want to preserve.

$U$ is a one-qubit unitary, but you apply it on two-qubits basis states. Does it apply only on one of the two qubits?

This could be helpful. https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/15532/21801

@TristanNemoz the idea is that the 2 by 2 unitary matrix acts on the two dimensional subspace spanned by 01 and 10. Alternatively using a change of basis you can make it act on the subspace spanned by 00 and 01 which effectively means to act on the second qubit given the first qubit is in the zero state

Assume that,
$$U = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}} u_{00}&u_{01} \\ u_{10}&u_{11} \end{array}} \right)$$
Then, you want to apply the two-level unitary
$$\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}} 1&0&0&0 \\ 0&u_{00}&u_{01}&0 \\ 0&u_{10}&u_{11}&0 \\ 0&0&0&1 \end{array}} \right)$$
to the two-qubit state $a|00\rangle + b|01\rangle + c|10\rangle + d|11\rangle$.
We can do that by following the procedure described in this answer

Step 1: Permute the computational basis states such that $|01⟩$ becomes $|11⟩$ but $|10⟩$ remains $|10⟩$
Step 2: Apply a single qubit gate on the first qubit if the second qubit is 1 (here I'm assuming little endian bit ordering)
Step 3: Undo step 1.

The circuit for these three steps would be

